# SuperAgent - Retry original req with new bearer token when unauthorized

Tags: javascript, ajax, authorization, superagent

**Problem:**

I'm trying to retry my original request using superagent.  Here is some pseudo:

```js
function postRequest({
    parameters
}) {
    return superagent.post(url)
    .set("Authorization", `Bearer ${process.env.initialToken}`)
    .send({data})
    .then(res => {
        if (res.unauthorized) { 
          // I want to make a API call, get a new token, then redo postRequest() with new bearer
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        throw err
    });
}
```

**Questions:**

I noticed that some devs handle this in the catch, others handle within the response.  I also noticed some use the `.on` plugin to check.

Looking at superagent docs, should I try a custom `retry()` ? Would I be able to use `request.auth('my_token', { type: 'bearer' })` in some fashion?  This may be simple, but it's hard to follow their docs for this use case.  Please let me know your thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

Solution - Was able to solve by just returning a call to the function again with the same initial parameters.  You can follow the same logic/pattern in your error handling.

Note - there are issues with the retry() API that doesn't work as expected for 401's and plugins are overkill for this usecase.